# Error with ifstream and ofstream in c++

Tags: c++, file, registration, ifstream, ostream

I am making a registration, for my database, but the compiller always says to me:

no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream::getline(std::__cxx11::string&, int&)’
   getText.getline(pass_password, data_count_password);

I do not understand where is the mistake in my code..Can anyone help me?

Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool is_user = false,startDatabase = false;
string file_text;
string username;
string password;
string repeat_password;
bool isCorrect = false;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
ofstream setText("user_data.txt");

ifstream getText("user_data.txt");

getText.getline(file_text,10);
if(file_text == ""){
    while(!isCorrect){
        cout << "For using our dataBase, please enter data for 
privacy \nUsername : ";
        cin >> username;
        cout << "Password : ";
        cin >> password;
        cout << "Repeat password : ";
        cin >> repeat_password;
        if(password == repeat_password){
            isCorrect = true;
        }else{
            cout << "Please, repeat and enter identistic passwords!";
            isCorrect = false;
        }
    }

    setText << username << password;
}else{
    int data_count_username = username.length();
    int data_count_password = password.length();

    string pass_password;
    string pass_username;

    cout << "Please enter your data " << endl << "Username : ";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Password : ";
    cin >> password;
    getText.getline(pass_username,data_count_username);
    getText.getline(pass_password, data_count_password);

    if(pass_username == username && pass_password == password){
        startDatabase = true;
    }
}

setText.close();
getText.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: And how can I fix it? - Just change string to the char array?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline apparently it accept char* not strings use file_text.c_str()

Comment: there is a sample down at the bottom of the page

Comment: So.....The ptoblem is char?

Comment: yeah it must be char*

Comment: There are more [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) functions that are *not* members of the stream objects. And the std::string header is `<string>`, not `<cstring>`.

Comment: But now the same problem is with `getText.getline(pass_username,data_count_username);
    getText.getline(pass_password, data_count_password);`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
std::getline(getText,file_text);
```